# URL href failing: Anchors, URL, and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, href

I am using javascript for smooth scrolling (in script tags below) and also have href for anchor links. All of the anchors are working fine but the javascript appears to be disabling the href for the URL. Can you help me rewrite this so that works as well?

```
<ul class="snip1143">
    <li class><a href="#home1" data-hover="Home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about1" data-hover="About">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#experience1" data-hover="Work">Work</a></li>
    <li><a href="URL HERE" data-hover="Blog">Blog</a>   </li
    <li><a href="#contact1" data-hover="Contact">Contact</a></li>

<script>

  $(document).on('click', 'a', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
      }, 500);
  });

</script>
```

Comment: before anything you should fix up your markup. 4th li needs a closing tag. and your ul needs a closing tag also

Answer (score 0):

event.preventDefault() is going to prevent the default, which for anchors is going to that url. You probably want to add a class to the anchors that you want to animate and select only those instead of preventing default on all anchor tags.

Comment: Please elaborate with code if possible. I'm a bit of a novice. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Acutally since you have unique `data-hover` for each element, all we have to do then is filter it by validating the value of their `data-hover` attribute.

```
<script>

  $(document).on('click', 'a', function(event) {
      if($(this).data('hover') !== "Blog"){       
       $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
       }, 500);
    }// since i noticed that you want to redirect the page once the Blog link is clicked
  });

</script>
```

Let me know if this helps you with your problem.

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me! Unfortunately, all other href links are now disabled outside of the "Blog" on the menu bar. Is there a way for me to fix this? The other mentioned perhaps using a class. Can you help me achieve this?

Comment: Hi if you want to set the default action for the link (hrefs) you just have to also set some validations for them in your condition statement lets say, "blog", "work", and "contact" tabs (or buttons or whatever you call them), if you want these 3 to execute their default redirection actions, include them here if($(this).data('hover') !== "Blog"){ and so it goes like this if(($(this).data('hover') !== "Blog") || ($(this).data('hover') !== "Work") || ($(this).data('hover') !== "Contact")){ then insert the event.preventDefault(); I hope you were enlightened with my answer.

Comment: These other URL links are throughout my page (not on the menu bar), but I need them to work. I understand how to get the URL links in the menu bar working, but what about those other links dispersed throughout my page? They are all disabled. What is a way that I can single those out in my condition?

Comment: Can you help me write it in a way that includes all in the menu except "Blog?" This way my other links on the page will work

Comment: hi kindly try the new codes above, i modified them removed prevent default, this time the rest of the links will be affected of the animation you set aside from the "Blog" link, try this and see if it will work on your requirements.